# Connect static generated website to a Nuxt 3 sub-route

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I search to link a nuxt route to a static generated website during build/SSG or SSR.

My example uses [Histoire](https://histoire.dev/) (a component-based documentation similar to Storybook). Histoire is built under `.histoire/dist` with a index.html. Also everything is static.

How can I connect this static generated website to Nuxt, such as it is reachable from `http://localhost:3000/doc/stories` in dev environment.

The site from Histoire has already a relative base url.

I have 2 strategies:

1. (SSG) Generate all the files and routes, then put them in the `public' folder.
2. Embedding the vue app (html, js, css) into nuxt page component (`pages/doc/stories`). I don't know how yet.

### Strategy 1: works only for the base URL

I tried to put the generated bundle into the `public` dir of nuxt before building the nuxt app as follow:
The generated `.histoire/dist` is placed into the nuxt `public/doc/stories` directory before building Nuxt. `http://localhost:3000/doc/stories/` is running as expected.
However, it is not possible to access the stories directly.
For exemple, the [meow demo component](https://vue3.examples.histoire.dev/story/src-components-meow-story-vue?variantId=src-components-meow-story-vue-0) is not reachable at `http://localhost:3000/doc/stories/story/components-atoms-meow-story-vue?variantId=_default`. It returns a 404-error as the generated site is a vue app.

EDIT: An [RFC pluggable child apps (multiapp)](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/30) to embed multiple nuxt apps will be implemented. It is not planned that it can use already built app though.